# How to overcom FormData limits when using Django rest framework?

Tags: forms, django-rest-framework

When using `Django rest framework` we need sometimes to send `FormData` instead of `json` because we can't send files using json. This creates 3 issues :

- Can't update field value to null.
- Can't send field value as array.
- Extension that update case mapping (snake_case/camleCalse) ignores FormData.

How to overcom these 3 problemes ?